# Отступ после div'а css

Tags: html, css

У меня есть див с баннером, как сделать так, чтобы после этого div'а был отступ?
Вот скрин с подробным описанием: номер телефона на белом фоне - это собсно сам див с инфой, а вот баннер после него - это объект, отступ до которого (т.е отступ от дива с инфой должен быть хоть какой-то)

[image: СКРИН]

Comment: а что вы пробовали сами ?

Comment: padding-bottom, не помог. Он наоборот только сделал высоту баннера с инфой больше.

Comment: Дык margin-bottom же... Не padding...

Comment: Как вы вообще верстать сайт собрались, если не знаете css, да и с отладчиками, похоже, не дружите... (впрочем, это не мое дело)

Comment: А он вытягивает родительский фон, т.е не отступ делает, а черным все кроет.

Comment: @Zelta вот именно, как я собрался, если за меня дизайн до этого другой верстальщик верстал, который, видимо, не профи, совсем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

margin-top на баннере

Comment: Я вот именно что хочу обойтись без этого, т.к нужно будет другие объекты двигать :(

Comment: Я не могу понять. Вам нужно чтобы между баннером и блоком с телефоном был отступ. Это можно сделать, если сделать отступ у блока с телефоном (margin-bottom), или у баннера (margin-top). Если не хотите сам баннер трогать, сделайте какую-нибудь обёртку у него. Хотя я не понимаю какой в этом смысл.

Comment: Разобрался, спасибою